# Can I display the second highest only (or 3rd.. so on) value using usort function?

Tags: php, mysql

here is my usort code and it makes me output the HIGHEST VALUE, i know that i can output it from HOGHEST TO LOWEST but i want to output SPECIFIC values

```
`<?php
usort($averagesa, function($a, $b) {
if ($a['avg'] == $b['avg']) {
    return 0;
}
return ($a['avg'] > $b['avg']) ? -1 : 1;
});
$highesta = $averagesa[0];
$highest_average = $highesta['avg']; 
echo $highest_average;`
```

here is a sample of the array content `

```
$querya1 = ("SELECT  ROUND(AVG(Compv11),2), dept_code , camp_code
                    FROM performance 
                    INNER JOIN employment 
                    ON employment.emp_code=performance.emp_id AND employment.dept_code=performance.dept_id
                    WHERE (empg_code=5 or empg_code=2) and (dept_code=10 and not stat_code=6)");
                    $resulta1 = mysql_query($querya1) or die(mysql_error());


// Print out result
while($rowa1 = mysql_fetch_array($resulta1)){
         $averagesa[1] = array(
        'avg' => $rowa1['ROUND(AVG(Compv11),2)'],
        'empg_code' => 1,
        'dept_id' => 3,
        'dept_code' => $rowa1['dept_code'],
        'camp_code' => $rowa1['camp_code']
    );
    echo "".$rowa1['ROUND(AVG(Compv11),2)'];
    $ga1 = "".$rowa1['ROUND(AVG(Compv11),2)'];
                    }

            ?>`
```

Comment: usort returns a bool (it worked or not), and sorts the array values.  So if your array has 5 items, after usort, array[0] will be the highest, array[1] will be the second highest, ...  Or did I misunderstand your question?  Look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php, the example shows the resulting array.

Comment: oh it worked perfectly lol. thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usort returns a bool (it worked or not), and sorts the array values. So if your array has 5 items, after usort, array[0] will be the highest, array[1] will be the second highest, ... Or did I misunderstand your question? Look at php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php, the example shows the resulting array